# Sleeping with the penis in the vagina

Tags: sex, penis, physical-health, vagina

Are there harmful side-effects of a couple sleeping with the penis in the vagina?

Comment: I doubt either of you would be able to pull that through. Neither would be allowed to move, and it will get really uncomfortable for both.

Comment: Side-effects? What exactly would be the intended effect?

Comment: Clearly this is a couple who like to fall asleep without moving after they are finished. And someone has told one of them that it's bad for them in some way, so they are coming here to see if it's true or not.

Comment: While potentially a bit odd, this seems like a reasonable question that has a well defined answer and I don't see why it should get down votes or votes to close.

Comment: Without going into research yet, common sense says it might not be a good idea. Sometimes small amount of urine is discharged while sleeping (not much, few drops only) so it can cause health issues if inside the vagina. Also, many times men get erections while sleeping, and I believe that it won't be comfortable for the female and might wake her up. All in all, think it's better to pull it out and just stay hugged together. :)